# UIView with fading ends?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit

In my app I'm using a UIView that is 2 pixels in height to separate two forms.

What I'm looking to do is take the ends of the view and add a 'fading' effect to them. For example, something like when you go on the iOS 6 app store under Top Charts in between Paid and Free there is some sort of separator.

How can I make something like that? I'm having a hard time explaining it so sorry for the poor question.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just use an image?

Comment: Not really but I don't know where to find one, and my graphic skills are far below basic

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will get you exactly what you want, but you could use a `CAGradientLayer` to create a gradient mask for the view's layer. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/08/adding-fading-gradients-to-uitableview/) that describes this. Play around with the color, locations and other parameters and see if you can get what you want.